# How to unit test interaction between FragmentDialog and Activity which implements interface

Tags: android, mockito, robolectric, android-testing

I have `MainActivity` that shows FragmentDialog (`EditIntervalFragment`) in order to capture user's input. Activity implements `EditIntervalListener` interface. In `onAtach` method fragment casts activity to `EditIntervalListener`.
I want to test that my `EditIntervalFragment` properly calls `EditIntervalListener` methods with correct parameters.

My initial intent was to use Roblectric and Mockito. The following code almost works.

```
@Test
public void shouldCallInterfaceAfterModify() {
    MainActivity hostActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    EditIntervalFragment editIntervalFragment = EditIntervalFragment.getInstance(0, TEST_NAME, TEST_DURATION);
    editIntervalFragment.show(hostActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "test");
    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) editIntervalFragment.getDialog();
    assertNotNull(dialog);

    EditIntervalFragment.EditIntervalListener activity = Mockito.spy(hostActivity);
    dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1).performClick();
    verify(activity).onIntervalChanged(0,TEST_NAME,TEST_DURATION);
}
```

The problem with this code that it uses real `MainActivity`. It means that all `MainActivity`'s logic will be executed. I want to avoid this. How can I do this?

**Update**
I found a way to not call real `MainActivity`. I created another activity, just for test.

```
public class ActivityTest extends FragmentActivity implements EditIntervalFragment.EditIntervalListener {

    //empty methods here
}
```

My test now looks like this

```
@Test
public void shouldCallInterfaceAfterModify() {
    ActivityTest hostActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(ActivityTest.class);
    ActivityTest spy = Mockito.spy(hostActivity);
    EditIntervalFragment editIntervalFragment = EditIntervalFragment.getInstance(0, TEST_NAME, TEST_DURATION);
    editIntervalFragment.show(spy.getSupportFragmentManager(), "test");
    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) editIntervalFragment.getDialog();
    assertNotNull(dialog);

    dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1).performClick();
    verify(spy).onIntervalChanged(0, TEST_NAME, TEST_DURATION);
}
```

But after test execution I receive error saying than only `spy.getSupportFragmentManager()` was called. I'm 100% sure that `onIntervalChanged` should be called.

Looking for help. How can I implement such kind of test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is always challange to make work spies when you don't control lifecycle.

What we are usually doing we extracting all not related functionality to utility classes and mock them in tests. It also helps with design of the application (Single class responsibility rule).

Of course it depends if you do something with this data. If it is just data class than I would have `Factory` for creating this data classes and again mock it in tests. All this requires proper DI (look to Dagger).

And there is nothing wrong with your approach but it doesn't force you to think about your app as small parts that interact with each other. But at the same time it brings more complexity which pays off later

Comment: Thank you. I was stuck with this `onAtach - getActivity - cast to listener` approach. Mainly because I see it everywhere (even AndroidStudio generates fragments like this). Now, I ended up with a dedicated presenter for my dialog. No connection with activity at all. And I like it :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this solution. Create an Activity that implements interface an keep track of all interaction.

```
public class ActivityTest extends FragmentActivity implements EditIntervalFragment.EditIntervalListener {

    public int mIntervalChangedCalls = 0;
    public int mPosition;
    public String mName;
    public long mDurationMillSec;

    @Override
    public void onIntervalChanged(int position, String name, long durationMillSec) {
        mIntervalChangedCalls++;
        mPosition = position;
        mName = name;
        mDurationMillSec = durationMillSec;
    }
}
```

My test looks like this

```
@Test
public void shouldCallOnIntervalChanged() {
    ActivityTest hostActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(ActivityTest.class);
    EditIntervalFragment editIntervalFragment = EditIntervalFragment.getInstance(0, TEST_NAME, TEST_DURATION);
    editIntervalFragment.show(hostActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "test");
    AlertDialog dialog = (AlertDialog) editIntervalFragment.getDialog();
    assertNotNull(dialog);

    dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1).performClick();
    assertThat(hostActivity.mIntervalChangedCalls).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(hostActivity.mPosition).isEqualTo(0);
    assertThat(hostActivity.mName).isEqualTo(TEST_NAME);
    assertThat(hostActivity.mDurationMillSec).isEqualTo(TEST_DURATION);
}
```

I'm not completely happy with this creation of a separate class just for test purposes. I suppose the same can be achieved with Mockito or Robolectric, but I do not know how.

So I'm still open for any ideas or suggestions. I'll accept my own answer, if no one gives better solution in a week.